# Merge two dataframes for BTC price and local time

Tags: python, bots, bitcoin, trading

I want to code a trading algorithm.

My first few lines of code are requesting the actual Bitcoin price from FTX Exchange and my local time. I want to have the open and close price for every minute.

I fail within the first lines of getting the time and the price tick in one row.

I want it to look like this:

```
|--------------------|
|   Time   |  Price  |
| -------- | ------- |
| 10:25:25 | 42313.0 |
| 10:25:31 | 42299.0 |
|--------------------|
```

But I only get jiberish like this:

```
[          0
0  10:25:25,         result
price  42313.0]
[          0
0  10:25:25,           0      
0  10:25:31,         result   
price  42313.0,         result
price  42299.0]
```

I hope you can help a newbie out.

My code is the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time 
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import gmtime, sleep, strftime   

opens = []
zeit = []
while True:

markets = pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://ftx.com/api/markets/BTC-PERP').json())

markets = markets.drop(['success'], axis=1)
markets = markets.drop(['ask'])

df1=(markets.iloc[[11]])

t_local = time.localtime()

mylocaltime=pd.DataFrame([time.strftime("%H:%M:%S",t_local)])
zeit.append(mylocaltime)
opens.append(df1)
merged = zeit+opens
print(merged)
sleep(5)
```

Comment: later i want to get the low and high price for every minute. with df.resample.ohlc

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you want to achieve:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.DataFrame()

for _ in range(5):
    response = requests.get('https://ftx.com/api/markets/BTC-PERP')
    data = response.json()['result']

    price = data['price']
    local_time = datetime.today().replace(microsecond=0)

    df = df.append({'time': local_time, 'price': price}, ignore_index=True)

    time.sleep(5)

print(df)
```

##### Output

```
     price                time
0  42228.0 2021-09-29 11:04:00
1  42229.0 2021-09-29 11:04:05
2  42242.0 2021-09-29 11:04:11
3  42245.0 2021-09-29 11:04:16
4  42222.0 2021-09-29 11:04:22
```

Comment: thank you very much. can i replace the "for _ in range(5)" loop with a while=True comand to get an ongoing table?

Comment: Of course, but be careful with `while True` loops! Remember that you need to exit this loop at some point without losing the data, so write the data to a `.csv` file or something similar.

Comment: i tried it and it works. i also reangranged with:  df_new = df[['time', 'price']]        thank you very much